# Mysql slow performance of very simple SELECT stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, freebsd

I am calling a stored procedure from JAVA, and it runs very slowly (about 120ms), even if it doesn't do much. For example:

```
BEGIN 
SELECT '1';
END
```

If I have the stored procedure do literally nothing, or if I run the select commands outside of a stored procedure (ie execute the select * from.. directly in code), then it runs quickly (3ms or so).

```
BEGIN
END
```

I have 50 other SELECT stored procedures, and they all run equally slowly. If I run any if these commands outside of stored procedures (ie execute the SELECT * FROM... statement from JAVA without stored procedures), then they run very quickly.

I did look around and found others with similar issues, but couldn't find an answer that works in my case. I confirmed that collation and character set are the same between the database, the table, and the stored procedure.

INSERTS seem to run quickly. It really seems isolated to SELECT commands.

Environment: FreeBSD 10.3, DB - MariaDB 10.0.21

**EDIT:** Running the stored procedures from mysql commandline executes very quickly (0.00 sec).

**EDIT:** I enabled the general log and have the following output:

> 184381 Connect  qwkdb@localhost as anonymous on productdb
>                   184381 Query    /* mysql-connector-java-6.0.2 ( Revision: c6da0fe501ad43d4ed6483b60ea796dc9fbe2d7b ) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client
>   , @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@l
>   icense AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_buffer_length AS net_buffer_length, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size
>   , @@query_cache_type AS query_cache_type, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@tx_isolation AS tx_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
>
> 184381 Query    SET NAMES latin1
>   184381 Query    SET character_set_results = NULL
>   184381 Query    SET autocommit=1
>   184381 Query    SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
>   184381 Query    SELECT name, type, comment FROM mysql.proc WHERE name like 'GetAttributeValue' and db <=> 'productdb' ORDER BY name, type
>   184381 Query    SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE `productdb`.`GetAttributeValue`
>   184381 Query    CALL GetAttributeValue('hi')

Comment: Does the stored procedure also run that slow when you call it directly? (Not from Java)

Comment: It's hard to say - 100 ms is still relatively fast and so it's hard to measure directly.

Comment: 100ms is actually slow. If you execute the query directly and look at the outputed execution time it should be only a few ms.

Comment: Running a slow vs fast query from Heidi SQL takes about the same amount of time. 60 to 120ms.

Comment: MySQL stored procs work different than other dbs,instead of in a global cache, they are stored in local sessions.  Each time you start a new session, it's forcing the procedure to compile.  There isn't much for performance gains in storedprocs on mysql.   (I should note that I'm not 100% sure on this for MariaDB 10.x)

Comment: Running a 100ms stored proc is pretty fast in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will disagree.. 100ms is very, very slow in my opinion. 
It also doesn't explain why inserts are fast - I can perform 550 inserts per second on this same database using stored procedures.

Comment: Also, I tried running the stored procedures from the mysql command line and it runs very quickly (0.00 sec is what's reported). I guess that means it's something to do with the client.. I'm using Connector/J and I also tried the built in jdbc client - same result for both.

Comment: Why are you using stored procedures to execute just queries? Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, where are located the application and the database? Are they in different machines? If yes, what is the network latency between then? You may be facing a network problem rather than a database performance.

Comment: The application and database are running on the same machine. 
Why would we not use stored procedures for queries? That's a pretty common design decision, I think?

Comment: 100ms is roughly the latency across the US.  Are you using kind of multi-node clustering?

Comment: Turn on the general log; CALL a SP through the connector; turn off the log.  Then look in the log to see if the connector emitted anything other than the CALL.

Comment: There's no multi node or replication or anything - everything is running locally, and it's a very simple setup - all default settings.

I checked the general log and there's a few things going on. These get called every time I execute the stored procedure. I added it to my question above. Not sure why it's calling all this stuff.. any ideas?